# what is the margarine metabolism in our body?

Tags: metabolism, health

**margarine** is commonly used food ingredients that contribute to both inflammation and

obesity , but actually I want to know the **margarine metabolism** in the human body

I can find some resources talk about its impact on health but I can't get the idea of its metabolism.

Comment: You probably need to look at the components of the margarine, then research the metabolism of each component.

Comment: What are its components  ?

Comment: Mostly plant oils. Have a look into [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Margarine) about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed to by @Chris [the Wikipedia link for margarine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Margarine) explains that these are formulated upon vegetable oil-based fats. Their melting points and other properties are adjusted by industrial hydrogenation of the unsaturated fatty acids in the vegetable oil.

Most unsaturated fatty acids present in nature are in the *cis* conformation at the double bonds. The hydrogenation process, if it is not carried to completion, produces the *trans* isomers of fatty acids. These so-called [trans-fats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trans_fatty_acids) are blamed for the undesirable side effects of consuming margarine, or other foods containing hydrogenated oils.

Most of the fatty acids present in margarine (i.e. *cis* unsaturated and saturated fatty acids) are metabolised by the normal route (β oxidation).